# Subtracting elements in a list OCAML

Tags: ocaml

```
let rec subtract_list myl = match myl with
    | [] -> 0
    | a::rest-> List.fold_right (fun y z -> y-z ) myl 0
```

I want to subtract elements in a list from themselves but I get the wrong result

subtract_lst [11;1;1;1] = 8 but the result i get is 10. What is wrong here?

Comment: Can you explain, step by step, what (you think) your code does? That will make it easier to pinpoint what specifically is confusing you. As is I think the question is too broad.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the fold_right works in this way (https://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/List.html):

```
List.fold_right f [a1; ...; an] b is f a1 (f a2 (... (f an b) ...)). Not tail-recursive.
```

so what do you have is:

```
11 - (1 - (1 - 1))
```

you can solve it changing your code like this:

```
let subtract_list myl = 
    match myl with
    | [] -> 0
    | a::rest -> List.fold_left (fun acc e -> acc - e) a rest
;;
```

or:

```
let subtract_list myl = if myl = [] then 0 else
    List.fold_left (fun acc e -> acc - e) (List.hd myl) (List.tl myl)
;;
```

Comment: Using `List.fold_left` is indeed better since it is tail-recursive (so that you don't have stack overflow issues in case of very long lists), it is perfectly possible to use `List.fold_right` like OP did: you just have to be careful with the order of the arguments of the function given to it: `List.fold_right (fun x acc -> acc -x)`.

Comment: Other point in your first solution: since you're pattern-matching on `myl` anyway, there's no need to use `List.hd` and `List.tl`: just bind the head and the tail in the pattern instead of using `_`.

Comment: yes, sorry, first proposal should have been:
```OCaml
let subtract_list myl = 
    match myl with
    | [] -> 0
    | a::rest -> List.fold_left (fun acc e -> acc - e) a rest
;;
```
should I edit the answer or just leave this comment here?

Comment: It's up to you, but I'd suggest to edit your answer directly. Comments might easily be overlooked. In any case, thanks for taking care of my remark.

Answer (score 1):

Another way of looking at this problem is that you're subtracting the sum of the tail from the head of the list. Because addition (unlike subtraction) is *commutative*, if we use this approach, it doesn't matter whether we use `List.fold_left` or `List.fold_right`, though the former will be tail-recursive.

```
let subtract_list =
  let sum = List.fold_left (+) 0 in
  function
  | [] -> 0
  | x::xs -> x - sum xs
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem you have, is that althought your list contains homogeneous values, it is not homogeneous in the meaning.

This would have been clearer for you with an explicit type like :

```ml
type t =
  ( int         (* The substracted *)
  * int list )  (* The subtractors *)
```

Which allow you to write this function :

```ml
let subtract_list
  : t -> int
  = function
    | (i, []) -> i
    | (i, tl) -> List.fold_left (-) i tl
```

As you have a list, and following the same pattern, you can write this function :

```ml
let subtract_list
  : int list -> int
  = function
    | [] -> 0 (* Empty list, nothing to do *)
    | i::[] -> i (* Case where you have nothing to substract *)
    | i::tl -> List.fold_left (-) i tl
```

Note : I have use a short circuit for substracting the element `List.fold_left (-) i tl` is the same as `List.fold_left (fun x y -> x - y) i tl`